# How to convert 1D array into 2D array with predefined positions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So, Here is my 1D array,

```
"seats": [
        {
            "available": "true",
            "column": "0",
            "name": "L1",
            "row": "0",
        },
       {
            "available": "true",
            "column": "1",
            "name": "L2",
            "row": "0",
        },
       {
            "available": "true",
            "column": "0",
            "name": "L3",
            "row": "1",
        },
        {
            "available": "true",
            "column": "1",
            "name": "L4",
            "row": "1",
        },
{
            "available": "true",
            "column": "0",
            "name": "L5",
            "row": "2",
        },
       {
            "available": "true",
            "column": "1",
            "name": "L6",
            "row": "2",
        },
       {
            "available": "true",
            "column": "0",
            "name": "L7",
            "row": "3",
        },
        {
            "available": "true",
            "column": "1",
            "name": "L8",
            "row": "3",
        },
 {
            "available": "true",
            "column": "0",
            "name": "L9",
            "row": "4",
        },
        {
            "available": "true",
            "column": "1",
            "name": "L10",
            "row": "4",
        },
];
```

So, above is the sample array, from the above i need to create 2D array and display the name on each.

Expected output:

```
CR  CR  CR CR
30-20  10-00
31-21  11-01

In this C - column and R is row for reference !
```

And so on, how to convert 1d into 2d and position the elements according to the row and columns from the array ?

My code trying's:

```
seats(list, elementsPerSubArray){
        var matrix = [], i, k;
        for (i = 0, k = -1; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (i % elementsPerSubArray === 0) {
            k++;
            matrix[k] = [];
            }
            matrix[k].push(list[i]);
        }
       
       for(var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            var cube = matrix[i];
            for(var j = 0; j < cube.length; j++) {
                console.log("s");    
            }
        }
    }
```

Its giving a straight line of outputs with missing outputs !kindly help,

Comment: please add a result from the given data.

Comment: Would the final 2d array look like this? `[ ["L1", "L2"], ["L3", "L4"], ["L5", "L6"], ["L7", "L8"], ["L9", "L10"] ]`

Comment: yes right, but as the total rows are 0,1,2,3 its needs to be in 4 rows and given columns !

Comment: My results are a long vertical list of array, thats it ! i need to posistion based on the row and column given in the array itself @nina

Comment: what has the presented result with the wanted to do?

Comment: The result needs to be posistioned according to the rows and columns with name as output from the array ! and for example consider that as table

Comment: why do you have ten elements and you want only 8?

Comment: its just an sample example for reference @NinaScholz

Comment: @hellodevs, come on! please add the result of the given data without adding meaninless information!

Comment: The answer provided from @NinaScholz is perfect as it is for bigger and smaller inputs. If you need to make Arrays of fixed length just create a constant and replace `[]` with `Array.from({length: columns})`; where `columns` is the constant number of columns that each row should have.

Answer (score 1):

You could assign `name` to the given row/columns.

```js
const
    data = [{ available: "true", column: "0", name: "L1", row: "0" }, { available: "true", column: "1", name: "L2", row: "0" }, { available: "true", column: "0", name: "L3", row: "1" }, { available: "true", column: "1", name: "L4", row: "1" }, { available: "true", column: "0", name: "L5", row: "2" }, { available: "true", column: "1", name: "L6", row: "2" }, { available: "true", column: "0", name: "L7", row: "3" }, { available: "true", column: "1", name: "L8", row: "3" }, { available: "true", column: "0", name: "L9", row: "4" }, { available: "true", column: "1", name: "L10", row: "4" }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { column, row, name }) => {
        if (!r[row]) r[row] = [];
        r[row][column] = name;
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: am not asking to chunk the array, asking for posistioning based on rows and columns in the array !

Comment: Is this a coding or a styling problem?

Comment: How to handle undefined ? from example 2nd wont be having elements its an empty space, in that case am getting undefined over that !

Comment: @hellodevs, if i would know what you are talking about. how much may i ask you to add a valid data structure for the wanted result of the given data ...?

Answer (score 0):

I used your `seats` as a basic variable array here.
In column and row attributes you already have the basic keys for a 2d-array, just need to run through it and put every column or every row together.
I did not make any tests other than check if the sub array is undefined

Now you'd have to loop through both dimensions again and print those names

```
var seats = []; // your content

let newSeats = [];

// rows as first dimension
for (let i = 0; i < seats.length; i++) {
  let row = seats[i].row;
  if (newSeats[row] === undefined) newSeats[row] = [];
  newSeats[row].push(seats[i]);
}

let newSeats = [];

// columns as first dimension
for (let i = 0; i < seats.length; i++) {
  let column = seats[i].column;
  if (newSeats[column] === undefined) newSeats[column] = [];
  newSeats[column].push(seats[i]);
}
```

Comment: @NinaScholz already answered similarly, but the OP needs, I believe, a string styled for it, or maybe some CSS.

Comment: We must have written an answer at the same time, in the question OP asks for converting to a 2d-array, it should be straightforward from there to display the seats